# About Converting QT Project to Visual Studio Project

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I have Qt Widget Application c++ project.

Is it possible for me to convert Qt gui part to VS 2013 c++ UI Windows Form?

I tried the below command, but didn't work.

```
qmake -tp vc
```

Comment: ```qmake -tp vc -r```

Comment: You can't convert GUI Qt-application to WinForms-application. ``-tp vc`` - create Visual Studio project, _.vs_, it's all. No conversion GUI.